# Encriptación de datos en java con javax.crypto

Tags: java, java-ee, encriptación

Tengo dos proyectos en Java EE2 en distintos servidores GlassFish, en un proyecto (Proyecto1) tengo un Login general (que permite logearse a varios sistemas) y en otro proyecto (proyecto2) tengo uno de los tantos sistemas.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es pasar una variable por URL, del proyecto1 al proyecto2 pero tiene que ir encriptada. Para esto estoy usando la clase de java crypto, y sinceramente recién me estoy metiendo en el tema.

Luego de realizar el login en proyecto1 encripto mi variable con el siguiente método:

```
public static String Encrypt(String plain) {
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null; 
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        PublicKey PublicKey = kp.getPublic();
        Cipher cipher;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, PublicKey);
        encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
   return bytesToString(encryptedBytes);

}

public static String bytesToString(byte[] b) {
    byte[] b2 = new byte[b.length + 1];
    b2[0] = 1;
    System.arraycopy(b, 0, b2, 1, b.length);
    return new BigInteger(b2).toString(36);
}
```

Y desde el proyecto2 previo a verificar los datos de logueo trato de desencriptarla
con el siguiente método:

```
public static String Decrypt(String result) {
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
    Cipher cipher;
    try {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        kpg.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        PrivateKey PrivateKey = kp.getPrivate();
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, PrivateKey);
        decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(stringToBytes(result));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(decryptedBytes);
}

public static byte[] stringToBytes(String s) {
    byte[] b2 = new BigInteger(s, 36).toByteArray();
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(b2, 1, b2.length);
}
```

Al desencriptarla me larga el error:

**javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error**

Alguien tiene una posible idea del por que del error?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por qué ese 1 al inicio del array de bytes?

Comment: @PabloLozano para que el "número" en el BigInteger tenga longitud fija (y evitar el caso de que los primeros bytes sean `0`). Se puede hacer sin eso, pero entonces tienes que calcular el tamaño del número, calcular el padding, etc.).

Comment: En todo caso parece que generas *pares de claves nuevos* para cada operación. Es como cifrar un texto con una clave y desencriptar con otra completamente distinta, escogida al azar. Lo que necesitas es que cada servidor tenga su par **fijo** (y creo que cada servidor necesita también la clave pública del otro).

Comment: Posiblemente sea eso, el tema es que no se porque el error, en todo caso debería andar bien y la clave desencriptada ser distinta a la encriptada

Comment: Inicialmente el problema es que se estás implementando mal el tema, lo primero que debes tener presente es si requires usar encripción simétrica o asimétrica, por lo que veo de tu código estas usando asimétrica pero pareces haber ignorado los requerimientos básicos para poder aplicar esta.

Comment: Parece que hay un problema de concepto; la clave *es lo que se usa para encriptar el mensaje*. La clave no se encripta ni desencripta, lo que se encripta es el mensaje. Si tienes problemas con criptología, recomiendo que empieces con encriptación simétrica (la clave es la misma para encriptar y desencriptar) como Triple DES y una vez estés familiarizado empieces a jugar con claves asimétricas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero a considerar al encriptar datos es que tipo de criptografia se va a utilizar, normalmente y según la necesidad se usa uno de los siguiente:

- **Encripción simétrica:** En este modo, el emisor y el receptor de la información encriptada han convenido previamente una contraseña para la encripción y desencripción de la información, un ejemplo claro es cuando se le coloca contraseña a un archivo .zip, cualquiera que tenga la contraseña podrá acceder a la información.
- **Encripción asimétrica:** En este modo, donde usualmente se utilizan pares de llaves de encripción, el receptor y emisor realizan un intercambio de llaves publicas, donde el emisor utiliza la llave del receptor para encriptar la información, solo el receptor será capaz de desencriptar la información pues el el único que tienen la llave privada con la que se puede desencriptar la data. Este es un modo más seguro que el anterior pues el receptor NUNCA tiene la necesidad de compartir su llave privada. Hay que aclarar que las llaves a utilizar en este modo deben generarse previamente para poder implementar el tema.

Superado lo anterior, es de tener en cuenta que la información encriptada se produce en bytes, es decir no es legible por el ojo humano y el transporte de la misma puede verse afectado de un sistema al otro, por lo cual es muy frecuente que esta información requiera se convertida a base64 o a una cadena Hexadecimal antes de enviarla a otro sistema.

Ahora, orientandonos al tema asimétrico que es el que se ve en el código que has implementado, lo primero que necesitas es generar un par de llaves. Para esto sugiero leer sobre la herramienta keytool que vienen incorparada con el java, aunque al ser una herramienta de linea de comandos es un poco mas complicada, para facilitar el tema sugiero usar una herramienta más visual como **KeyStore Explorer** donde podrás crear un llavero y el par de llaves correspondientes sin mucho esfuerzo.

Ahora, como el intercambio de información solo es en un sentido (según lo que entiendo de lo que estás haciendo) solo necesitas 1 único par de llaves. Entonces la teoría es así: en la aplicación 1 que es la que envía la información lo único que necesitas es la llave publica del receptor, hay varias formas de como cargar la llave, desde tomarla de un llavero de java hasta cargarla desde un archivo plano que contenga solamente el modulo o que este codificada en x509.

Supongamos que la llave esta en formato x509 (este valor se puede obtener desde KeyStore explorer) y quemada en el código, no es la mejor practica y por lo tanto no se recomienda, pero para este caso didáctico lo haré así.

```
private static String LLAVE_X509 = "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";
```

Ahora debemos cargar e inicializar una llave en java para realizar la encripción, esto podría hacerse así:

```
X509EncodedKeySpec rsaSpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(HexBin.decode(LLAVE_X509));
```

Ahora que ya tenemos una llave para usar y como solo es 1 dato a encriptar y que se asume no es inmensamente largo la función que podrías utilizar es la siguiente:

```
public static byte[] encriptar(KeySpec keySpec, byte[] data) throws Exception {
    PublicKey key = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
```

Es importante tener en cuenta que la llave publica a utilizar en este caso es de tipo **RSA**, adicionalmente se utilizará un algoritmo de **RSA** con modo **ECB** y relleno **PKCS1**, es importante tener en cuenta esto pues es lo mismo que tendrá que especificarse al momento de desencriptar la información. Finalmente deberas codificar el resultado en base 64 para que pueda ser enviado a la otra aplicación, hay muchas librerías (inclusive en él mismo java) que hacen esto, puedes buscar en google cual utilizar.

Ahora, vamos del lado de la aplicación 2, la que recibe la información encriptada, entonces lo primero es que como la información llegó en base64 deberás decodificarla a un array de bytes para luego desencriptarla con la llave privada, en este caso asumiremos, como suele ocurrir, la llave está en un llavero java, entonces la función a utilizar puede ser la siguiente:

```
public static byte[] desencriptar(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    FileInputStream archivo = new FileInputStream("/ruta/al/llavero/java/keystore.jks");
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    //Contraseña del llavero
    keystore.load(archivo, "123456".toCharArray());

    //se carga la llave mediante el alias o nombre que se le dio a la llave
    Key key = keystore.getKey("millave", "123456".toCharArray());
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
```

Si te fijas, el llavero tiene una contraseña, igualmente el par de llaves, para este caso del ejemplo tanto el llavero como el par de llaves tienen la misma contraseña, pero este NO siempre es el caso.

Con lo anterior ya puedes implementar la encripción asimétrica, no sobra decir que este es un ejemplo básico pero que contiene la base de como implementar la encripción y desencripción, hay otros detalles mas elaborados como el uso de otros algoritmos probablemente más seguros que el de este ejemplo, o para encriptar grandes volúmenes de información es necesario otros ajustes adicionales, pero ya es cuestión de que investigues mas a fondo el tema.